# TextArea without Scrollbars

Tags: javafx-2

I have a [TextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) in my application that actually takes no interactions from the user.

Is there a way to either

1. Remove the scrollbar entirely and let me handle what happens when the scrollbar *would* appear?
2. Use a different object to display text to the screen? I need to be able to append text, but I don't need it to be highlight-able or take any user input.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, but wouldn't a Label with word wrap enabled be a good fit?

Comment: Labels are non-editable. I need to be able to modify the text of my object in the program. I just don't want the *user* to be able to modify the text.

Comment: They are pro-grammatically editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your needs, you need to use label.

If you need TextArea, to remove scrollBars, you can do the next :

1. Use lookupAll(java.lang.String selector) method to find scrollBars, and
2. call scrollBar.setOpacity(0.0) for each found scrollBar.
   2a. Don't call setVisible(false), as visible property (I believe) is used to TextArea to control scrollBar visibility.

Comment: Oh, perfect. Thank you, @Alexander Kirov. I can't seem to find a way to fire an Event for when the text reaches the end of the label and begins to be truncated, however. Any ideas?

Comment: The same way : lookup Text.class (it is a node, which represents the rendered text), and add a listener on the height property of it. And you can track its height - but don't forget about label's insets and padding.

Comment: Another way - when you use TextArea, you can add listener on vertical scrollBar visible property.